# How state initialization works in React?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I've got a main component which local state called **inputValue** is going to be updated when an onChange event occurs. In my main component and also calling a customHook, this custom hook is going to receive the **inputValue** as a parameter.

In my custom hook I declare another local state called **customValue** using useState and initialized to **inputValue**, which is receiving from my main component. After the first render when I try to access to the value of customValue it does not give me the latest value coming from inputValue, it keeps giving me only the value which it was initialized.

Part of my main component code:

```
const[inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("hi");

const onChange = () => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setInputValue(e.target.value)
};

const value = useCustomHook(inputValue);
```

My custom hook:

```
    export default function useCustomHook(inputValue){
      const[customValue, setCustomValue] = useState(inputValue);
    
      return console.log(customValue);
   };
// It always returns "hi", besides it gest called in each re-reder of the main component.
```

I  know to solve this I need to to something like

```
setCustomValue(inputValue)
```

So my question is... **customValue** is not supposed to be automatically initialized to latest value coming from **inputValue** in each re-reder of my main component?

Answer (score 1):

you should pass an event listener to your event handler function like:

```
const onChange = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setInputValue(e.target.value)
};
```